# Using google chrome frame with Django

Tags: javascript, html, django, internet-explorer, google-chrome-frame

I am  trying to use Google Chrome Frame in my Django app. 
Inserting `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1">` into the header doesn't do the trick.

Right now, this is what my header looks like:

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="chrome=1"> 
  <title>Amuse Me</title>
  <link href='/static/style.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/jquery-1.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/base.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Chrome Frame plugin is installed in your IE?

Comment: Yes. Chrome Frame is installed. I tried it in a site which uses the html Video tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your page might be cached as suggested in [quirksblog](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2009/09/google_chrome_f.html):

> **Cache**
>
> When I was doing research I used one
>   test page and constantly changed the
>    tags in the . The problem
>   was that IE/Frame seemed to be caching
>   not only the page, but also in which
>   rendering engine it should be shown.
>   Therefore a simple page refresh won’t
>   help you here.
>
> Fortunately Twitter user jdalton came
>   up with a solution: simply append a
>   pseudo-query such as ?123 to the page
>   URL. That bypasses the cache and
>   forces the browser to re-evaluate the
>    tags.

Answer (score 0):

Open your code in Google Chrome's developer tools and look for html errors, and check your resource headers.

Comment: The only warning we get is: `Resource interpreted as stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html`. This is common in Django, and is irrelevant to this problem. There are no errors.

Comment: That error is *not* common in Django. If you see it all the time, you have something wrong with the configuration of your static server, which is very very likely to be related to your problem.

Comment: Agreeing with Daniel - check your server settings? Is this happening for a single CSS file or multiple? In 2 years of working with Django I've not had that issue once